# Post restoration

Tags: posts, backup

I backed up a version of my wordpress site which contains several posts. Lets call this website website A. I have a different website which also contains several posts. Lets call this one website B. Lets say I have a recent backup of website A, and I restore the contents of website A using a backup of website B. Is it possible to restore the posts contained in the backup of website A to the current state of website A (current state meaning restored with the backup of website B).

Comment: You could restore Website A - Export the Content - Restore Website B - Import the Content.

Comment: Thank you! When you import, does it append or overwrite?

Comment: If you import the exact same xml content file twice, you will have duplicates of the same content. It won't overwrite anything.